# order of javac classpath affecting whether classes can be found

Tags: java, classpath

I have a jar file, `MyClasses.jar`, that contains a class `MyReader`.  I have a client class `BuildReader` which uses it:

```
// BuildReader.java
MyReader reader = new MyReader();
```

`BuildReader.java` is in the current working directory for this example (and is the only file present).  If I compile with:

```
javac -cp .:/path/to/MyClasses.jar BuildReader.java
```

Then I get an error that javac can't find the class `MyReader`.

```
BuildReader.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
MyReader file = new MyReader();
^
symbol:   class MyReader
location: class BuildReader
```

However, if I compile instead with:

```
javac -cp /path/to/MyClasses.jar:. BuildReader.java
```

it compiles just fine.  Everything I've looked at online suggest that the only thing that could be a problem is that perhaps there are other versions of `MyReader` about; there aren't.  Can anyone help me to understand why the order of the javac classpath is causing compiler errors?  I am not the creator of `MyClasses.jar`, if that's relevant.

Comment: Silly question, but you're not using Windows are you?

Comment: The *order* within the classpath should *only* matter when you have **several** occurrences of some class X in there - because then the **first**  X to be found will be used. But that doesn't explain what you claim to observe.

Comment: Now that you've answered the Windows question, I'm curious if you've checked the MyClasses jar for MyReader. I know you said you don't have any other copies, but is it possible you only checked your directory structure and didn't check the jar?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say, but I bet you are using Windows, where the classpath separator is ';', not ':'.

Comment: Definitely using a mac!